# Direction on using the appropriate conjunctions "and"/"or"/"nor" in a medical setting

Tags: conjunctions

Quick background: I'm a medical professional and have a question on the proper use of the conjunctions **"and" "or" "nor"** when writing patient notes. See examples below:

In a section of a patient note called History of Present Illness (HPI) and Review of Systems (ROS), a health care provider would write something to this extent in the patient note as pertinent to the patient presentation:

> **HPI**
>
> The patient denies having any fever, chills, **and**/**or**/**nor**
> fatigue. The patient reports having a cough, ear pain, **and**/**or** rhinorrhea.
>
> **ROS**
>
> **CONSTITUTIONAL**: Negative fever, chills, **and**/**or** fatigue.
>
> **ENT**: Positive cough, ear pain, **and**/**or** rhinorrhea.
>
> **CARDIAC**: Denies chest pain, edema, **and**/**or**/**nor** palpitations.

Could someone help me identify the correct conjunction to be used in the provided examples above: **and**, **or**, **nor**?

Could you also provide reasoning/explanation to the correct use of these conjunctions in the above setup?

This will be very helpful and informative for my colleagues and me.

**Thank you!**

Comment: You might have half a dozen questions here. I'm going with "The patient denies having any fever, chills, **or** fatigue. The patient reports having a cough, ear pain, **and** rhinorrhea."

Comment: I see no reason or evidence for patient notes to use any special interpretation of and, or, and not. They are, after all, to be read by other human beings who use, presumably, standard English.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I believe your thought process may be incorrect, and here is why:  If you say "The patient denies having any fever, chills, **or** fatigue" you are then implying that there is a choice. They either deny fever and chills **or** fatigue. However, if you state "The patient denies having any fever, chills, **and** fatigue" then you imply that they deny the whole list. This is at least my thought process. I just want to make sure that I'm on the right thought process here vs suggestion for a different thought process with a collaborating explanation.

Comment: Yes, *or* indicates choice. I could have fever or chills or fatigue or any two. But if I have none, it is quite clear to write I deny having any fever, chills, **or** fatigue. Or, deny having fever, chills, fatigue (as in @Xanne list, where all apply). To deny having fever, chills *and* fatigue is to say I don't have all three, but maybe two. I'd need to clarify: *No, doctor, I don't have all three, just fever.*

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of documents on the internet. The basic point, however, is that you use standard English.  There is no special use of conjunctions in this field.

See [this](https://Guidelines%20for%20the%20History%20and%20Physical%20Exam%20Write-up%20Department%20of%20Medicine%20Boston%20University%20School%20of%20Medicine) for one example. It includes the following:

> 15. Overall Evaluation/Considerations:

> □ Be legible.

> □ No plagiarism from outside sources or other health care providers.  (cite literature when you use it).

> □ Use proper grammar and spelling.

> □ Avoid abbreviations if possible and make sure your audience understands the abbreviations.  It is your responsibility to make the write-up understandable to the reader.

> □ The write up should be of appropriate length.  The assessment and plan should be 1-2 typed pages.  In general the remainder of the write up should be 3-5 pages.
> □ The write up should be organized according the format outlined above.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment is not helpful. I'm not looking for an explanation on how to write a SOAP note. That is very clear - gosh I hope it is for most people who finish healthcare   What I am looking for is clarification on the exact use of the conjunctions: ***and, or, nor** as listed in my OP.

Comment: The exact use is the same in health care as it is in any other field. There is no special rule for conjunctions. The same possibilities for ambiguity and misunderstanding arise.